# JS to add button to add text to a Textarea does not work

Tags: javascript, html, servicenow

These textarea fields are on a servicenow page:

```
<textarea id="activity-stream-comments-textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="incident.close_notes"></textarea>
```

I have this JS in place to add text to them:

```
// text values for update and resolve strings
var text_update = "Last Action\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nOn " + today + " I \n\nNext Action\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nWait for reply\n\nNext Action Date\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nNot known - review in 7 days if no update before then from customer.";

var text_resolve = "Symptoms\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\nCause\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\nSolution\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n";

// create input element for the option to add an activity note
var inputNote=document.createElement("input");
inputNote.type="button";
inputNote.value="Add Note";
inputNote.onclick = AddNote;
inputNote.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default btn-ref icon icon-info");
inputNote.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; top:120px; right:40px; width:120px");
document.body.appendChild(inputNote);

// AddNote Function - add the note to the activity update textarea
function AddNote() {
    if (!$("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").val()) {
        $("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").val (text_update);
        $("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").css({'background-color':'yellow'});
        $("#activity-stream-comments-textarea").focus();
    }
}

// create input element for the option to add  resolution note
var inputResolve=document.createElement("input");
inputResolve.type="button";
inputResolve.value="Resolve";
inputResolve.onclick = AddResolve;
inputResolve.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default btn-ref icon icon-info");
inputResolve.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; top:160px; right:40px; width:120px");
document.body.appendChild(inputResolve);

// AddResolve Function - add the note to the activity update textarea
function AddResolve() {
    if (!$("#incident.close_notes").val()) {
        $("#incident.close_notes").val (text_resolve);
        $("#incident.close_notes").css({'background-color':'green'});
        $("#incident.close_notes").focus();
    }
}
```

The option to add a note works fine (adding to the textarea with an id value of `activity-stream-comments-textarea`).

However, the option to add a resolution note (to ID `incident.close_notes`) does not work.

As in, I click on the button to add a resolution note, and the note is not added in the same way it is added with the AddNote function. I can see no errors in the console when I click on the button to add a resolution note.

I know the ID of the textarea is correct for the resolution field.

The only thing I wondered is, is the option to add a resolution note not working because the ID contains a dot whereas the ID for the activity note does not contain a dot?

I have tried testing with just the resolution option on its own to isolate any conflict with the AddNote function, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suppose is correct, the dot cause the problem add `\\` will solve your problem.

```js
var text_resolve = "Symptoms\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\nCause\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\nSolution\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n";

// create input element for the option to add  resolution note
var inputResolve=document.createElement("input");
inputResolve.type="button";
inputResolve.value="Resolve";
inputResolve.onclick = AddResolve;
inputResolve.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default btn-ref icon icon-info");
inputResolve.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; top:160px; right:40px; width:120px");
document.body.appendChild(inputResolve);

// AddResolve Function - add the note to the activity update textarea
function AddResolve() {
    if (!$("#incident\\.close_notes").val()) {
        $("#incident\\.close_notes").val (text_resolve);
        $("#incident\\.close_notes").css({'background-color':'green'});
        $("#incident\\.close_notes").focus();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="incident.close_notes"></textarea>
```

Another elegant way is use :  `$('[id="incident.close_notes"]')`

```js
var text_resolve = "Symptoms\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\nCause\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\nSolution\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n";

// create input element for the option to add  resolution note
var inputResolve=document.createElement("input");
inputResolve.type="button";
inputResolve.value="Resolve";
inputResolve.onclick = AddResolve;
inputResolve.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default btn-ref icon icon-info");
inputResolve.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; top:160px; right:40px; width:120px");
document.body.appendChild(inputResolve);

// AddResolve Function - add the note to the activity update textarea
function AddResolve() {
         
    if (! $('[id="incident.close_notes"]').val()) {
         $('[id="incident.close_notes"]').val (text_resolve);
        $('[id="incident.close_notes"]').css({'background-color':'green'});
         $('[id="incident.close_notes"]').focus();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="incident.close_notes"></textarea>
```

And i don't know if was a typo error but you didn't close `<textarea>`